# Toast "Press back again to close" gives error when pressing back too often

Tags: java, android, eclipse, toast, back-button

**My goal:**

When a visitor goes back to the first page of my app, a toast appears to let the visitor know that he can press the back button again within 3 seconds to close the Android app.

**Specific problem:**

When you went back to the first page and the toast appears, the code works fine when you press back only once but when the toast appears and you press back more than one time, the following error message appears: "**(appname) has stopped**".

Does anyone know what causes this error message and how I can solve this?

MainActivity.java file:

```
// Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

private Boolean exit = false;
@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else {
        if (exit)
            this.finish();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                exit = true;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }, 3 * 1000);
        }    

    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the stack trace please, otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: Try initializing your handler with `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when you fast-click the back button, it's calling `this.finish()` multiple times, resulting in the crash.

You can do two things to prevent that.  The first is to set the `exit` flag back to false after you call `this.finish()`.

In addition, to prevent a race-condition from multiple fast-clicks attempting to close the app, you can set a timestamp that will only allow one close event to be scheduled in each three second time window:

```
    private Boolean exit = false;
    private long timeStamp = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            if (exit) {
                exit = false; //added
                this.finish();
            }
            else {

                //added:
                if (timeStamp == 0 || (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp) > 3000) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    exit = true;

                    timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); //added

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            exit = false;
                        }
                    }, 3 * 1000);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Just curious : why Boolean instead of boolean ? Other than that, excellent answer, you deserve my vote ;)

Comment: @2Dee  That was part of the OP's code, I just left it in there.  Thanks!

Comment: Oops, missed that, sorry :-/ .

Comment: @DanielNugent I used your code but now the toast doesn't even show up anymore... And when I press back on the first page, I immediately get the "app has stopped" error message. Any idea why?

Comment: @Stan I just noticed that I forgot to initialize `handler`.  Take a look at the updated answer with `private Handler handler = new Handler()`.  I just tested it and it looks like it's working fine now with the proper initialization.